# More than one parameter in syntaxis MobileService.GetTable<Usuarios>().Where() to retrieve data from an Azure SQL DB

Tags: select, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have been working on an WP8 app which has to access a DB stored in an Azure SQL Server. So far, I have managed to store data on the tables, an read a row (or rows) which contain specific data on one of the fields. My question is how to retrieve a row but with more than one parameter, so my code to use would be something like this:

```
await App.MobileService.GetTable<Users>().Where(Users=> Users.field1== value1 & Users.field2 == value2).ToListAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{......
.....
....
}
```

Everything which I came across googling, just samples a selection using one parameter only.
I hope you could help me.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any expression in the `Where` clause that can be converted into an OData filter query by the client SDK, and filtering based on two values is certainly possible. Remember that you need to use the *logical AND* operator (`&&`) instead of the *bitwise AND* (`&`).

```
var users = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Users>()
    .Where(Users => Users.field1 == value1 && Users.field2 == value2)
    .ToListAsync();
// do something with users list
```